# AFJsonRequestOperaton - How to cancel?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation

I am interested to implement the pattern recommended [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/405). I am looking at creating a `NSMutableSet` and storing my `AFJSONRequestOperation`s to it so I can cancel these requests when my View Controller has invoked `viewDidDisappear`.

I just looked at the source code for `AFJSONRequestOperation` and I just found out that it doesn't have a public method for canceling the operation similar to `NSOperation`...

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AFJSONRequestOperation` is a subclass of `NSOperation`, therefore it inherits the `cancel` method from it.

Simply call `cancel` on the operation.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see it!